# Equivalent of $mdThemingProvider.definePalette() (AngularJS Material) in Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-material, angularjs-material

which is the equivalent of

```
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('paletteName',PaletteConstant);
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('paletteName');
```

in Angular Material?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out the Angular Material docs on theming? https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Yes, but I'm searching for a typescript solution. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2):

Angular Material Equivalent is:

```
$primary: mat-palette($mat-green);
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

Below is complete themes.scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/_theming';

@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-green);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-blue);

$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);

.dark-theme {
  $dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
  $dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-green);

  $dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```